# How do I get model/record attributes in their proper types, and not just strings?

Tags: plugin-development, string, models, records

Here's my record (model is nearly identical):

```
namespace Craft;

class Recurly_PlanRecord extends BaseRecord
{

  public function getTableName()
  {
    return 'recurly_plans';
  }

  protected function defineAttributes()
  {
    return array(
      'sortOrder'      => AttributeType::SortOrder,
      'code'           => AttributeType::String,
      'max'            => AttributeType::Number,
      'min'            => AttributeType::Number,
      'annual'         => AttributeType::Bool,
      'base_endpoints' => AttributeType::Number,
      'endpoint_code'  => AttributeType::String,
      'base_cost'      => array(
        'type'     => AttributeType::Number,
        'decimals' => 2,
      ),
      'endpoint_cost'  => array(
        'type'     => AttributeType::Number,
        'decimals' => 2,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In the DB, the column types seem to be set correctly based on this.
What I can't figure out how to do, is actually get data back in the specified types, not just strings.

Here's me using it in a service:

```
$record = Recurly_PlanRecord::model()->find();
var_dump($record->attributes); // all strings :(
var_dump($record->base_cost); // string '1402.50' (length=7)

$model  = Recurly_PlanModel::populateModel($record);
var_dump($model->attributes); // all strings :(
```

What I *want* is `float 1402.50`. What I get is a string.

I'm having the same problem with `AttributeType::Bool`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure if you are aware, but P&T recently added Craft::dd($variableName) as an option and has been very helpful when troubleshooting issues like this.

Comment: Thanks @JasonMcCallister, didn't know about that. Getting the same results from `Craft::dd`, however. Showing strings for everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently the only thing Craft does in [BaseModel->setAttribute()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/models/BaseModel#setAttribute-detail) and [BaseRecord->prepAttributesForUse()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/records/BaseRecord#prepAttributesForUse-detail) is some normalization when the attribute in either case happens to be [AttributeType::DateTime or AttributeType::Mixed](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/enums/AttributeType).

All other attribute types will be returned directly as the database returned them (as a string).

However, I agree with you that we probably should be doing more to return the exact type as the attribute specifies.  Since that's potentially a big breaking change, though, it'll have to wait until Craft 3.0.

The good news is, thanks to PHP's loose typing system, you can still workaround most cases.

For example a bool will come back as either the string `'1'` or `'0'`.

Using that in a PHP conditional `if ($myModel->boolAttribute)` will evaluate to true or false.

Using your float example: `'1402.50' + 100.00`, PHP will properly cast that to `1502.50`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Brad. The way this came up is I had a controller just dumping models to json: `$this->returnJson($arrayOfModels);`, but noticed everything was strings when I really wanted to retain things that were floats, bool, etc.

Comment: Ahh... in that case, you might just need to do some casting yourself.

Comment: I'm thinking I'll override the model constructor and do my casting there, if that makes sense. But +1 for getting this on the books for Craft 3!

Comment: I'd like to point out that this is a Yii issue. The justification by the Yii development Team was that using strings to represent integers avoids integer overflow on 32-bit machines. Personally I still think it's a bit of a silly decision.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up overriding BaseModel->setAttribute() and BaseRecord->prepAttributesForUse() in my plugin.

Works well! Right now I'm just handling Bool and Number types.

Posted this solution here: http://craftcookbook.net/recipes/324